# discord.py translate command googletrans

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I recently found this bug in my translate command and when I try to translate the word "good" to spanish I get this error `Command 'translate' raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. I'm not sure if this is an issue on my end because translating other things like sentences works fine

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RGkJ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HwG9.png

````
@client.hybrid_command(name = "translate", with_app_command=True, description="Google translate a message to a language", aliases=["tr"])
@commands.guild_only()
async def translate(ctx, language, *, message):
    language = language.lower()
    if language not in googletrans.LANGUAGES and language not in googletrans.LANGCODES:
        await ctx.send("Invalid Language. Try Again.", ephemeral=True)
        return
    
    text = ' '.join(message)
    translator = googletrans.Translator()
    text_translated = translator.translate(message, dest=language).text
    embed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor)
    embed.add_field(name=f"**Input  :**", value=f"```\n{message}```",inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"**Output  :**", value=f"```\n{text_translated}```",inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url=f"{ctx.author.avatar.url}", text=f"Translated to {language.capitalize()}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: That's the only error I get, I don't get a traceback

Comment: There should be a traceback in the console where you're running the bot. How are you running the bot? Do you have this issue with other words, or just with `good`? What happens if you remove the exclamation point?

Comment: I've tested it a bit more and it's a little strange, It works fine with other words and if I remove the exclamation point it still doesn't work. Guess the bot is just the grinch and hates good

Comment: Can you make a new Python script (not a bot) just using the `googletrans` module and try to translate "good" into Spanish? Do you get the same error, and if so do you get a full traceback?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mw1TcSMm

Full traceback with the word "good" into spanish

Comment: Yup. I'm getting the same error, too. Were you able to successfully translate other words or phrases? I'm not able to currently...

Comment: I can translate other words or phrases, yes. It may be an issue with the library since I've heard there were other issues with this library.

Comment: What version of googletrans are you using? I remember I had a similar issue, and then upgraded to Version `4.0.0rc1` which solved it.

Comment: I'm also using 4.0.0-rc1

Answer (score 0):

`translate()` returns `None` when the input cannot be translated.
This can happen if:

- The input is invalid
- Something is wrong with the translation API (this is likely the case for you)

Hence you need to check if `translate(...)` returns `None` before you access the `text` attribute.

Something like this:

```py
# ...
translation = translator.translate(text, dest=language)

if translation is None:
    await ctx.send("The input could not be translated!")
    return

# proceed with translation...
text_translated = translation.text
```